# How can I do username in reviews on django?

Tags: python, django

I'm doing reviews on django, but I want the user to not be able to enter any name. I want the username in the reviews to match the username of his profile

models.py

```
 class Reviews(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField('Отзыв', max_length=3400)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name='Родитель', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(BookModel, verbose_name='книга', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

views.py

```
class MoreInfoView(View):
    """ """
    def get(self, request, id):
        book_info = BookModel.objects.filter(id=id).first()
        stuff = get_object_or_404(BookModel, id=self.kwargs['id'])
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
        return render(request, 'bookapp/more_info.html', context={
            'id': id,
            'book_info': book_info,
            'book': BookModel.objects.all(),
            'total_likes': total_likes,
        })

class AddReview(View):
    """Add Review"""
    def post(self, request, pk):
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        book = BookModel.objects.get(id=pk)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.book = book
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('more_info', args=[pk]))
```

forms

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Reviews
        fields = ("name", "text", 'name_user')
```

Comment: Exactly what field would contain the username? Can you share the `ReviewForm`?

Comment: name_user is the field I want to use.
Just name can be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add user manually after validating `ReviewForm`

I also added some changes(suggestions)

`models.py`

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField('Отзыв', max_length=3400)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name='Родитель', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(BookModel, verbose_name='книга', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

Setting **blank=True** makes the field optional.

`views.py`

```
class MoreInfoView(View):
    """ """
    def get(self, request, id):
        book_info = BookModel.objects.filter(id=id).first()
        stuff = get_object_or_404(BookModel, id=self.kwargs['id'])
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
        return render(request, 'bookapp/more_info.html', context={
            'id': id,
            'book_info': book_info,
            'book': BookModel.objects.all(),
            'total_likes': total_likes,
        })

class AddReview(View):
    """Add Review"""
    def post(self, request, pk):
        user = request.user

        # User has to be authenticated to create a review. And backend must 
        # validate it. You should raise PermissionDenied as response or 
        # redirect user to the login page, or something similar.
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            raise PermissionDenied()

        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        book = BookModel.objects.get(id=pk)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.book = book
            form.user = user
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('more_info', args=[pk]))
```

`forms.py`

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Reviews
        fields = ("name", "text")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advise to work with a [**`CreateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) that will simplify a lot of the logic. You can implement this as:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class AddReviewView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ReviewForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('more_info', args=[self.kwargs['pk']])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.book_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.name_user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

In your `ReviewForm` you thus remove the `name_user` as `fields` element.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Review` instead of <s>`Reviews`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `…Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`BookModel`</s> to `Book`.